# Match Div Position on Click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, position, match

So I've encountered an easy problem I feel like, just don't know the exact way to solve. I'm attaching this animation gif I created to illustrate exactly what it is I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: animation of matching div position on click]

I also created an [example here](http://cdpn.io/KtrdH) of how far I got, which is not far. I'm just getting the position of the right div element on click. I'm assuming I would need to get the left position of div and minus that from the position of right and add either margin-top or position top to adjust position of left div element.

Any help would be greatly apreciated and thanks ahead of time. If you can edit and fork new pen with code that would awesome or you can post code back here.

http://cdpn.io/KtrdH

```
 $('.static-container').each(function() {
 $(this).click(function (e) {
   var posX = $(this).offset ().left,
       posY = $(this).offset ().top;
   alert((posX) + ' , ' + (posY));
   });
 });
```

**Solution**

```
 $(function(){
    $(".static-container").click(animateDescription);
 });

 function animateDescription(){
    var topCss = $(this).offset().top;
    var relativeTop = topCss - 68;
    $(".dynamic-container").animate({
        top: relativeTop}, 500);
 }
```

**Also Works**

```
 $('.static-container').each(function() {
   $(this).click(function (e) {
       posY = $(this).offset ().top;
       $('.dynamic-container').animate({top: posY -68});
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to achieve if you use jQuery. I have put up a [JS Fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BP3Ld/) based on the example you provided. Basically the changes I've made were

1- Positioning the dynamic-container div relatively to its parent so it can "float" around...

```
.wrapper .column-a .dynamic-container {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
    position:relative; 
}
```

2- Added this javascript to handle the click event and slide the dynamic div accordingly

```
$(function(){
    $("div.static-container").click(animateDescription);
});

function animateDescription(){
    var topCss = $(this).offset().top;
    var relativeTop = topCss - 20;
    $("div.dynamic-container").animate({
        top: relativeTop}, 500);
}
```

Notice that I'm subtracting the 20 pixels to accommodate the padding, but it DOESNT need to be hard-coded, with a bit of math and jquery you can calculate the actually padding by subtracting the height from the outerheight (or something between those lines)

[JS Fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BP3Ld/)

Comment: Ahh perfect, a solution. Makes perfect sense, I was over thinking the situation, but I knew it was something quite this easy. Thanks for posting demo, I have aslo implemneted this now here http://codepen.io/alvaram/full/KtrdH/ and posted new code above

Answer (score 2):

If the div that will go move is static in x axis:

```
$('.static-container').each(function() {
 $(this).click(function (e) {
       posY = $(this).offset ().top;
   $('.animation-div').offset({top: posY});
   });
 });
```

Comment: Another solution. Also works, slightly less code. Posted new code above as well.

Comment: After you can increment an animations with Jquery or CSS transition duration and delay.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on something in which I had to denote the x and y position of the mouse and used this code.

```
$("#wrapper").mousemove(function(e) {
    window.x = e.pageX;
    window.y = e.pageY;

    $('body').click(function() {

        $(".animating_div").css({
            'top' : window.y + 'px',
        });
    });
});
```

So for what you are wanting animate the div with the y position.  You will have to use absolute positioning on the div you are wanting to manipulate.

use `animate` though instead of `css`.  Or even better, you could add a class with a dynamic positioning, and use a `addClass`, `removeClass` to get a quicker effect.

Add a little more code next time so people can see you have attempted this.

Comment: Ultimately this is the correct logic. I had more code that was invalid so just wanted to post what I had working. Will post more code next time. Thx for sharing. Posted working solutions above.